# Classification with sk-learn: handle missing categorical features at prediction

Tags: python, scikit-learn, missing-features

I my project I train a BaggingClassifier. As the used data contains categorical features, I use the pandas framework(get_dummies) to encode them. After this, I train the classifier.

Now I wanted to do a prediction. It returned this error:

```
ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 12 and input n_features is 6.
```

I do understand why I get this error.
Required features from the model: 12

Given features inside the prediction data set: 6

Because of the encoding, the training dataset got spreaded to 12 features in this case.
The encoded data which I use for the prediction has only 6 features, as it is only one row of data, that doesn't get spreaded at all during the encoding.

This Example shows the problem:

Original training dataset

```
Age| Color  
35 |'Orange'
55 |'Black' 
75 |'Red'
```

After pandas get_dummies:

```
X                              
Age| Orange | Black| Red       
35 | 1      | 0    | 0         
55 | 0      | 1    | 0         
75 | 0      | 0    | 1
```

Prediction data set

```
X
Age| Orange|       
35 | 1     |
```

The feature set for the prediction doesn't fit the set that is required from the model, as it misses the features "black" and "red". And I cannot think of a nice way how to solve this.

Is this a mistake from a wrong approach?

Answer (score 0):

For this application, you should try [sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder). It basically does the same as dummy variables in pandas, but when calling `fit` on your training data, it will remember which values there where and which columns the correspond to. If you then `transform` your test data, it will create an array with the same number of features for the training data.

Comment: Sorry for the late response.
The problem is, that I pickel the trained model for later use. With OneHotEncode, I would need to pickel another object to keep the information. This means I would need to lead two data from the filesystem when I do the prediction, which is in a very time critical context, and might run next to up to 1000 other predictions.

What really would be nice is, if you could get the feature list straight of the model, which somehow has to be saved in there anyway. But it seems there is no way for this

Comment: No, the feature list is not saved in the model. How would the model know which features you fed it? The OneHotEncoder should by tiny and you can put it in the same pickle file. This should really not create any overhead.